# F5 redirect to different domain along with useragent

Tags: f5, big-ip

Our production application is configured with F5.

**If request comes from mobile** to http://xxx.abc.com/show.aspx?show=homePage

I want to create rule is F5 to redirect to a different domain like

http://xxx.xyz.com/show.aspx?show=homePage

My doubt here is if the initial URL contains User Agent since users are browsing from mobile, after the rule is created is by default the User Agent is also passed along.

The URL that we are trying to redirect to should also contain User Agent since my application renders mobile pages based on useragent.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer for your question is on Devcentral.f5.com:

**https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/simple-url-redirect-irule**

There are several ways to achieve what you're looking for and also include or exclude user agent data.  It will depend on exactly what the redirected server needs.  Just search on DevCentral for URL Redirect and you'll get more answers than you'll need.  Here's an overview of URL redirections:

**https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/2-minute-tech-tip-url-redirects**